# Getting null complex java object calling a webservice

Tags: jax-ws

Hy,

I have a problem using JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean to consume a web service. Everything is fine until I have to receive a complex java object type from the call to a web service method but I get a null object. The soap I receive is this :

```
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-   
      envelope"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ns:altaLiquidacionResponse 
      xmlns:ns="http://wsPice" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-
      envelope" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"><ns:return 
      xmlns:ax21="http://wsPice/xsd"  
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:type="ax21:ResultadoLiquidacion"><ax21:respuesta>ERROR 0: Fecha 
      anterior a 1-1-2015</ax21:respuesta><ax21:resultado>KO</ax21:resultado> 
      </ns:return></ns:altaLiquidacionResponse></soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the service looks like this:

```
   @WebService(targetNamespace="http://wsPice")
   public interface PiceServicePortType extends java.rmi.Remote {

@WebMethod  
     public ResultadoLiquidacion altaLiquidacion(
            @WebParam(name="wspassword") String wspassword,@WebParam(name="cci_id") String cci_id, 
        @WebParam(name="pln_nombre")String pln_nombre,@WebParam(name="trm_nombre")String trm_nombre,
        @WebParam(name="jvn_documento")String jvn_documento,@WebParam(name="jvn_nombre")String jvn_nombre,
        @WebParam(name="ind_fecha")String ind_fecha, 
        @WebParam(name="ind_coste")BigDecimal ind_coste, 
        @WebParam(name="ind_referencia")String ind_referencia) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;


  }
```

The ResultadoLiquidacion object looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "return")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class ResultadoLiquidacion implements java.io.Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@XmlElement(name= "respuesta")
private java.lang.String respuesta;

@XmlElement(name = "resultado")
private java.lang.String resultado;

public java.lang.String getRespuesta() {
    return respuesta;
}

public void setRespuesta(java.lang.String respuesta) {
    this.respuesta = respuesta;
}

public java.lang.String getResultado() {
    return resultado;
}

public void setResultado(java.lang.String resultado) {
    this.resultado = resultado;
}
```

}

So the wierd thing is although I get a soap response, in java the ResultadoLiquidacion object is null. Other problem is I cannot see the implementation of client web service because of JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean. Any ideas?

Thanks